# How to send a hashed password to DRF and get authenticated

Tags: django, angular, authentication, hash, django-rest-framework

I'm working on authenticating users in Django, and I know that Django keeps all the passwords hashed in the data base,

so in order to secure the user credentials, I have to hash the password in my front end (Angular2) before sending it to my back end (Django rest framework).

The problem is that I don't know if Django excepts hashed passwords or is he capable of comparing it to the existing one, and if so , can any one pin point me to the right way.

any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: No, you must send the unhashed password. Django then hashes the password and compares the hash the the stored hash.

Comment: Yeah, @knbk is right and you might want to take a look at https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt for authentication.

Comment: yeah, I'm currently using DRF-jwt and sending the password without hash, I just wanted to know if that would affect data transfer (security side)

Comment: Hashing (using an appropriate password-based key derivation function) is a means to protect passwords at rest, such as in your database. It is not meant to protect passwords in transit. For that you should use e.g. TLS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to hash the password in Angular. Django will not understand a password hashed by Angular, since Django hashes passwords in a different way and has no information indicating that what you are sending is a hash. Even if you were able to has them the same way, Django would hash it again, which would not work. That is,

```
H(password) != H(H(password))
```

For a single hash function, `H`.

Send the password as plain text to the server. Protect the password by transferring all data over TLS/SSL. Django will accept the plain text password, compare the hashes, and authenticate the user as normal.